# Geometry problem prove $\angle{ADB}=3\angle{BAC}$

Tags: geometry

Acute $\triangle{ABC}$, point $D$ is on side $AC$ so that $AD=BC$, $CF$ bisects $\angle{ACB}$. Point $E$ on side $AB$ so that $DE \parallel CF$ and $AE=CD$. **Prove: $\angle{ADB}=3\angle{BAC}$**

[image]

Comment: A review of the [Selected Propositions from Euclid’s Elements of Geometry Books II, III and IV (T.L. Heath’s Edition)](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/Courses/MA232A/MA232A_Mich2017_PentagonSelection/EuclidPentagonSelection.pdf) might be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\angle ADB = 3\angle BAC$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4004908/prove-that-angle-adb-3-angle-bac)

Comment: @Saeed Thanks! The link is great, exactly what I need.

Answer (score -1):

In quadrilateral ABCD, we have AD = BC and                ∠DAB = ∠CBA.                In ΔABD and ΔBAC,                AD = BC[Given]                AB = BA[Common]                ∠DAB = ∠CBA[Given]                ∴ Using SAS criteria, we have ΔABD ≌ ΔBAC          (ii) ∵ ΔABD ≌ ΔBAC                ∴ Their corresponding parts are equal.                ⇒ BD = AC          (ii) Since ΔABD ≌ ΔBAC                ∴ Their corresponding parts are equal.                ⇒ ∠ABD = ∠BAC. Hence Proved

Comment: Thanks but... Is this suggested answer for this problem? Looks like the answer is for a different problem, with different known facts and different target statement to prove.